# Pandas: create named columns in DataFrame from dict

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, dataframe

I have a dictionary object of the form:

```
my_dict = {id1: val1, id2: val2, id3: val3, ...}
```

I want to create this into a DataFrame where I want to name the 2 columns 'business_id' and 'business_code'.

I tried:

```
business_df = DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict,orient='index',columns=['business_id','business_code'])
```

But it says `from_dict` doesn't take in a columns argument.

> TypeError: from_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can iterate through the items:

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame(list(my_dict.items()),
                      columns=['business_id','business_code'])
Out[11]: 
  business_id business_code
0         id2          val2
1         id3          val3
2         id1          val1
```

Comment: ```my_dict.items()``` for Python 3

Comment: This does not quite answer the question, as the docs specify that a columns keyword argument may be used: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: check for the version, it is available in 0.23.0

Answer (score 12):

To get the same functionality as the documentation and avoid using code workarounds, make sure you're using the most recent version of Pandas. I recently encountered the same error when running a line of code from the Pandas tutorial:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6])]),orient='index', columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

I checked the version of Pandas and found I was running version 22, when version 23 is available.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
Out[600]: '0.22.0'
```

I upgraded using pip:

```
c:\pip install --upgrade pandas
```

I confirmed my version updated to 23, and the same from_dict() code worked without error. No code modifications required.

Answer (score 4):

[From version 0.23.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html), you can specify a `columns` parameter in `from_dict`:

```
my_dict = {id1: val1, id2: val2, id3: val3, ...}
prepared_dict = {i: x for i, x in enumerate(my_dict.items())}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(prepared_dict, orient='index', columns=['business_id', 'business_code'])
```

Note: I also answered in kind on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44882176/604687).

Comment: I tried this out using pandas 0.24.2 and Python 3.6.8 got the following error:
`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (3, 2)`

Comment: @anthls That is not enough information to solve your issue, which I do not think is directly a result of `from_dict`. If you seek help on Stack Overflow, I would recommend asking a separate question.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear - I wanted you and others to know I'd tried your answer but it didn't work for me. I used the following code (using pandas 0.24.2 and Python 3.6.8): `import pandas as pd
my_dict = {"id1": "val1", "id2": "val2", "id3": "val3"}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index', columns=['business_id', 'business_code'])`
and got the error I mentioned (I've left out the full stack trace). I used the accepted answer and it worked so I don't require resolution of my issue but thought you might like to know.

Comment: @anthls I see what you mean now, thanks. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

create the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_as_2d_ndarray)
```

create a sorted list of column names from the dictionary - adjust the key karg as need to grab the sorting value from your dict, obvilous the dictionary the data must have consistent shapes

```
col_names = sorted(list(col_dict.iteritems()),key=lambda x:x[0])
```

reshape and set the column names

```
df.columns  = zip(*col_names)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is with respect to TypeError you faced. As per Pandas documentation, from_dict will take the keyword 'columns' only if the orient = 'index'.