# Set column names in pandas data frame from_dict with orient = 'index'

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I looked already at this question: [pandas create named columns in dataframe from dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340844/pandas-create-named-columns-in-dataframe-from-dict/32280888). However, my example is slightly different.

I have a dictionary:
`my_dict = {'key1' : [1,2,3], 'key2' : [4,5,6], 'key3' :[7,8,9]}`

And I created a pandas dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')`, which is row oriented. However, when writing `columns = ['one', 'two', 'three']` I get an error, as in the link above.

How do I name them?

Comment: The way to solve it is answered in your linked question (with one less column). Just look at the accepted answer: `pd.DataFrame(list(my_dict.iteritems()),columns=['business_id','business_code'])`, so in your case `pd.DataFrame(list(my_dict.iteritems()),columns=['one','two','three'])` (credit to [Andy Hayden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240268/andy-hayden))

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't set the column names on the next line?

```
my_dict = {'key1' : [1,2,3], 'key2' : [4,5,6], 'key3' :[7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')
df.columns = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Should work.

Answer (score 13):

[From version 0.23.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html), you can specify a `columns` parameter in `from_dict`:

```
my_dict = {'key1': [1, 2, 3], 'key2': [4, 5, 6], 'key3': [7, 8, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index', columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my_dict = {'key1' : [1,2,3], 'key2' : [4,5,6], 'key3' :[7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='columns')
df.columns = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Changed orient from index to columns. This worked for me.